# How to redeem subscription promo in react-native-iap android?

Tags: react-native, react-native-iap

this code is working for subscriptions, How to redeem subscriptions promo in android .
Note I have generated them via  google play store .
Thanks alot in advance I have been working on it for days.

`` const result = await IAP.requestSubscription({skus:['my sku'],subscriptionOffers: [{sku: 'my sku', offerToken}]});`

`const result = await IAP.requestSubscription({skus:['mysku'],subscriptionOffers: [{sku: 'mysku', offerToken}]});`
`
this is currently working  but I want to redeem promo subscriptions in android

Answer (score 0):

You can redeem it through playStore. You can use this link which will navigate to playStore's redeem page.

Linking.openURL('https://play.google.com/redeem?code=')

Comment: nope thats through google playcards  not redeeming in app promo codes